# Java GUI, why isn't my carButton not displaying the picture I drew

Tags: java, actionlistener, graphics2d

For my program, I'm trying to display something that I drew with JRadioButtons and the images won't show up. I have system.out.println("test"); to see if my actionListener is working and its displaying the "test" but not showing up with my drawing. If anyone can help that'll be great. It wouldn't let me put all the classes so I put everything in the pastebin, if anyone has any questions please feel free to ask
https://pastebin.com/h3fAjhQw

public class Final {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new AutoFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Nittany Auto");
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: You should try to post a [mcve]. Having said that, usually the first line of an overridden `paintComponent` method is a call to the superclass method, i.e. `super.paintComponent(g)`. Refer to [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) which is part of Oracle's Java tutorials.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You problems start here `class selectListener extends JPanel implements ActionListener {`

You're extending from `JPanel`, so when you do `add(cc)` in the `actionPerformed`, you're actually adding the component to the panel and not the frame.

Your problems are further compounded by the fact that `CarComponent` does not provide any kind sizing hints for the layout managers to work with.

Having said that, I would suggest making use of delegation workflow instead.  That is, create a concept of "renderer", which can used by a "render pane" to draw the actual thing you want draw, then create different implementations of the "renderer".

The reason for this is, the "render pane" provides sizing hints automatically  which makes setting up the UI easier and the "renderers" decouple the workflow, for example...

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {
        private String message;
        private JLabel label;

        private JRadioButton carButton = new JRadioButton("car");
        private JRadioButton truckButton = new JRadioButton("truck");

        private VechicalRendererPane rendererPane;

        public MainPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            message = "Nittany Auto";
            label = new JLabel(message);
            label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
            southPanel.add(carButton);
            southPanel.add(truckButton);
            add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
            group.add(carButton);
            group.add(truckButton);

            ChoiceActionListener choiceActionListener = new ChoiceActionListener();

            carButton.addActionListener(choiceActionListener);
            truckButton.addActionListener(choiceActionListener);
            carButton.setSelected(false);

            rendererPane = new VechicalRendererPane();
            add(rendererPane);
        }

        protected class ChoiceActionListener implements ActionListener {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (carButton.isSelected()) {
                    rendererPane.setRenderer(new CarRenderer());
                } else {
                    rendererPane.setRenderer(null);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public interface VehicalRenderer {
        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d, Dimension bounds);
    }

    public class VechicalRendererPane extends JPanel {

        private VehicalRenderer renderer;

        public VehicalRenderer getRenderer() {
            return renderer;
        }

        public void setRenderer(VehicalRenderer renderer) {
            this.renderer = renderer;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            VehicalRenderer renderer = getRenderer();
            if (renderer != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                renderer.paint(g2d, getSize());
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public class CarRenderer implements VehicalRenderer {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d, Dimension bounds) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.red);
            g2d.fillRect(130, 70, 150, 80);

            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));

            g2d.drawRect(150, 40, 70, 100);

            g2d.setColor(Color.black);
            g2d.drawRect(200, 80, 20, 10);

            g2d.fillOval(135, 138, 30, 30);
            g2d.fillOval(168, 138, 30, 30);

            g2d.fillOval(215, 138, 30, 30);
            g2d.fillOval(248, 138, 30, 30);
        }
    }

}
```